# Git Help: forgot to add file, switched branches, now the files are missing

Tags: git, git-branch, git-checkout

I have the following problem:

I used a git repository to save my code. I created a new file in my branch and forgot to add it to git. After I switched back to the master and back to my branch, these files are suddenly gone.

Is there a way to recover them? Thank you!!

**Edit**: I found them in my **master branch** now. Can someone explain what happened?

Comment: what do you mean they are in master? Are they committed to master?

Comment: no they werent added or committed at all. I switched to the master and then back to my branch and suddenly they werent there anymore. When I switched back to master, they reappeared.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is expected.

> I forgot to add it to git

This means that Git doesn't know about the file, i.e. the file is not tracked. When a file is not tracked, the file will be "available" regardless of the branch on which you are on.